# Powershell Remove Lst element from array

Tags: powershell

I need to remove the last element from my array. This is adulterating the results.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Scripts\OPEX_XIP_Comparison\ -Recurse -Include *.opex,*.xip -Exclude  *.pax.zip -File | ForEach-Object {
$a += @($_.Name)}
$ht = @{}
$a | foreach {$ht["$_"] += 1}
$ht.Keys | where {$ht["$_"] -gt 1} | foreach {write-host "DUPLICATE ELEMENTS WERE FOUND $_" -ForegroundColor Cyan }
```

My array $ht have this elements: (the last element is a number greater than 1 (13052))

```
 kancel.xip                     1                                                                                                                
 MHENKDV060213.opex             1                                                                                                                
 mhe_fish_ko.xip                1                                                                                                                
 IMG_1928.xip                   1                                                                                                                
 mhe_mangrove_worm.xip          1                                                                                                                
 IMG_1959.xip                   1                                                                                            
                                13052
```

My result is : DUPLICATE ELEMENTS WERE FOUND (It writes the string because of that value)

Comment: `$a` variable isn't initialized. Use `$a = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Scripts\OPEX_XIP_Comparison\ -Recurse -Include *.opex,*.xip -Exclude  *.pax.zip -File | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}` instead.

Comment: it looks like you have a key that is blank. is that correct? if so, filter that value out _before you add it to your hashtable_.

Comment: Hi JosefZ and Lee, JosefZ your aproach initialize the $a variable with all files fullnames and diretorys. @Lee, how can i do "filter that value out before you add it to your hashtable."?

Comment: I would suggest that you use `-Filter` instead of the slower `-Include` option, unless there's a chance you could have files existing which begin with those specific extensions but are not exactly them. Unfortunately `-Filter *.doc` also includes `*.docx`, `*.docm`, however, it's probably still a little quicker if you use both `-Filter` and `-Include` together.

Comment: What is your goal? You get list of files, some of them have duplicate names ( but they are stored in different folders ). What should you do with them ? You need to check only if there are duplicate names? Or remove both of duplicate entries? Or leave only one of all duplicates?

Comment: @filimonic the goal is to check only if there are duplicate names. And leave a message if there are or not.

Comment: @Paulo - if you are really seeing items with no name value, then using `Where-Object` should let you filter out the blanks. i don't see how you are getting blanks, tho. ///// if all you want is to find dupe file names _regardless of the directory_, then using `Group-Object` and the `.Count` property seems the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said,

> the goal is to check only if there are duplicate names.

---

The short way

```
$duplicatesExist = @(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'S:\SCRIPTS\FileTest' | 
    Group-Object -Property 'Name' | 
    Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 }).Count -ge 1
```

---

And more complex, but faster on huge number of files way.

It is faster because it only enumerates file names, and ignores all unnecessary `FileInfo` data like size, attributes etc, which is always processed by `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet

```
$fileNames = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('S:\SCRIPTS\FileTest', '*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories) |
    ForEach-Object { return [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_) } |
    ForEach-Object { return $_.ToLower() } |
    Where-Object { $_.EndsWith('.opex') -or $_.EndsWith('.gpx') } 
$fileNamesUnique = $fileNames | Sort-Object -Unique
$duplicatesExist = $fileNamesUnique.Count -ne $fileNames.Count
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for everyone, for your great help, add it mrore information to my knowledge.  @filimonic, your approach was the solution.

Comment: @Lee, thanks again for you answers and for your great help to understand the solution.

Comment: @Paulo, I found a mistake on first example: `.Count -gt 1` => `.Count -ge 1`. Fixed my post.